# Хранение ссылки в штрих коде

Tags: php, barcode

Подскажите, возможно ли в штрих коде типа С128 хранить ссылки?
Ибо при попытке добавить что-то, что не является числом, вылетает ошибка.
Использую milon/barcode

Comment: Можно хранить цифры, буквы латинского алфавита и некоторые спецсимволы.

Comment: Присмотритесь к ошибке, возможно она содержит полезное послание. Кроме того, она прилетела из кода, который вы можете спокойно прочитать и разобраться в проблеме.

Comment: Храните в базе ШК как отдельную строку и в этой же строке храните расшифровку, что мешает? Любой тип ШК пишете в базе типа BarCode|Link и не паритесь задавайте хоть EAN13 хоть COD39... Главное что бы не повторялись